# JQuery in Liferay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, liferay

This is my code in jsp file. How can I show only 2 "article" after rendering the page with opportunity to click "show more"?

The main difference from other question is that I want to show more `<div>` blocks, but not `<li>` and other. And I failed to iterate throgh whole blocks. :(

```
<aui:form name="journalForm" id="journalForm">

    <c:forEach items="${articleModelList}" varStatus="counter"
        var="article">

        <div class="span3">

            <c:if test="${(counter.index % 3) == 0}">
                <div class="article animated fadeInLeft">
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${(counter.index % 3) == 1}">
                <div class="article animated fadeInDown">
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${(counter.index % 3) == 2}">
                <div class="article animated fadeInRight">
            </c:if>
            <div class="well">
                <h3>${article.articleName}</h3>
                <div class="article__content">
                    <div class="seo-header">Click to view content</div>
                    <div class="seo-content morecontent">
                        <p class="text-success">${article.articleContent}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</c:forEach>
</aui:form>
</div>

<div id="loadMore">Load more</div>
<div id="showLess">Show less</div>
```

I've came to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
size_li = $("#myList .span3").size();
x = 2;
$("#myList .span3 .article").each(function(index, obj) {
    if (index < 2)
        $(obj).attr("display", "block");
});
```

But it doesn't work. I've read a lot of documentation, but with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a kind of magic, because I've tryied to solve it all day and came to success after 2 minutes after publishing it here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
size_li = $("#myList .span3").size();
x = 2;
$("#myList .span3 .article").each(function(index, obj) {
    if (index < 3)
        $(obj).show();  });

});
```

and `display: none` in `css` file.